# how I get city id from a php page

Tags: php

I am creating a registration form for my web site. In my registration form, there are two select boxes to select user's district and there city. So I need to do it, when a user select their district then automatically display city select box with cities which relevant to above selected district. To do this I used AJAX and PHP. I used findcity.php page to display the city in my register.php page. My problem is when I am try to get city id from the register.php page I cant get it. It I need to get to send with other data from register.php page to database.

from my register.php page

```
<div>
<label for="district">District <img src="../images/required_star.png" alt="required" /> : </label>
<?php

    require_once ('../includes/config.inc.php');    
    require_once( MYSQL2 );

    $query="select * from district order by district_id";
    $result = mysqli_query( $dbc, $query);

        echo '<select name="district" class="text" onChange="getCity(' . "'" . 'findcity.php?district=' . "'" . '+this.value)">';
        echo '<option value="">-- Select District --</option>';

        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) { 
            echo '<option value="' . $row[0] . '"';

            // Check for stickyness: 
            if ( isset( $_POST['district']) && ( $_POST['district'] == $row[0] ))    
                echo ' selected="selected"';

                echo " >$row[1]</option>";    
        }
        echo '</select>';
?> 

</div>    
<div>
    <label for="city">City <img src="../images/required_star.png" alt="required" /> : </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="reg_locationid" id="reg_locationid" value="56" />
    <div id="citydiv" style="position: relative; top: -14px; left: 130px; margin-bottom: -26px;">
        <select name="city" class="text">
            <option>-- Select City --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is findcity.php page

```
<?php

$districtId=$_GET['district'];

require_once ('../includes/configaration.inc.php'); 
require_once( MYSQLCONNECTION );

$query="select city_id, city_name from city2 where district_id=$districtId";
$result=mysqli_query( $dbc, $query);



echo '<select name="city" class="text">
        <option>-- Select City --</option>';

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) { 

    echo '<option value="' . $row[0] . '"';

    // Check for stickyness: 
    if ( isset( $_POST['city']) && ( $_POST['city'] == $row[0] )) { 
        echo ' selected="selected"';

        //echo '<input type="hidden" name="city"  value="' . $row[0] . '"'; 

    }
        echo " >$row[1]</option>";  

}

echo '</select>';
```

?>

this is my ajax functions

```
function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
    var xmlhttp=false;  
    try{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)    {       
        try{            
            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            try{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1){
                xmlhttp=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}



function getCity(strURL) {      

    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                    document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                      
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use sessions for that...

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo '<select name="district" class="text" onChange="getCity(' .
      '\'findcity.php?district=\'+this.value+\'&city=\'' .
      '+document.getElementsByName(\'city\')[0].value)">';
```

or use sessions as Learner suggested.

Also, the code would be much less ugly if you extracted JavaScript from HTML...